# Select random input in Lambda function

Tags: tensorflow, keras

How do I forward data only from randomly chosen input in Lambda function preferably in Keras.

Specific scenario - I am splitting input layer to 2 CNN towers (each with slightly different architecture). I would like to merge them back, but forward only output from random one of those towers. This random check would be done for each image, so in theory each tower would be used 50% of the time.

Using power of Google I came up with

```python
def get_random_tower(v):
    #Random number from 0-1 (inclusive)
    val = np.random.randint(2)
    var = K.variable(value=val)
    #based on that number, either select first or second tower
    out = K.switch(var, v[0], v[1])
    return out
...    
added = Lambda(get_random_tower, output_shape=out_shape)([tower0, tower1])
...
```

This compiles and tries to fit, but accuracy does not improve.

Answer (score 0):

Your `var` won't work the way you intended.

To make it work, you'd need to make a tensor that works like a Bernoulli random variable. Unfortunately, as for now, Keras backend doesn't provide something like this out of the box.

You can implement it with a uniform random variable though, for example like this:

```
var_uniform_sample = K.random_uniform(shape=(1,))
var = K.greater(0.5, var_proba)
```

(I haven't tested the details, but I've used something exactly like this, but with other shape).

Comment: using code provided I get exactly same result as with my code, on cifar10 exactly 0.100 accuracy. I suspect your code did something right, because I was forced to use batch_size of 1. Edit recommendation `var_uniform_sample -> var_proba`

Comment: Well, I've said that you need to work out the details - my solution is exactly aligned with what you had